# Take the rgb value on my layers with linked layes

Tags: jsx, photoshop, photoshop-script

This is my photoshop file call app.psd. I need to take all RGB value of all layers. Some layers are imported from another psd files. I wrote a sample jsx file to print it.

But it is not working. Can anyone help me!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fh7Y.png)

```
for (var i=0; i<layerNode.length; i++) {

  getColors(layerNode[i].layerSets);
   for(var layerIndex=0; layerIndex < layerNode[i].artLayers.length; layerIndex++) {

   var Colour=layerNode[i].artLayers[layerIndex];
   app.activeDocument.activeLayer = Colour;
   var R = Colour.rgb.red.toFixed(2);
   var G = Colour.rgb.green.toFixed(2);
   var B = Colour.rgb.blue.toFixed(2);

   alert("Red = " + R +"\nGreen = " + G + "\nBlue = "+ B);
   }

}
```

Comment: What's ``RGB value of all layers``? How layer can have one rgb value? Or do you mean Rgb value of all pixels of all layers? In your code you're mixing ``ArtLayer`` and ``SolidColor``: ``rgb`` is a property of color, not layer

Comment: Yes, I means RGB value of all pixels. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fh7Y.png) check this image link. Each layer has shapes and I need the RGB value of that shapes. That is why I mentioned the RGB value of every layer.

Comment: If your shapes are rectangular and have one color, you can first find their bounding box and then use color sampler in the coordinates of bounding box to get their color. Check the scripting reference for those.